# AttributeError: module 'wx' has no attribute 'Timer'

Tags: python, wxpython

here is the code that I tried to run:

```py
import wx
app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, "Hello World")
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

displayed error in spyder:

> AttributeError: module 'wx' has no attribute 'Timer'

What's the problem?

Comment: Hi! Could you post more of the error message? This is only the last line, and it would be helpful to see a traceback.

Comment: Edit the question to show the full traceback as properly formatted text.

Comment: You haven't declared a `wx.Timer()`, so there's that. Run your code from the command line, it should work.

Comment: I just ran your code without any error. What version on wx are you using?